# SaveAs Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save as a new workbook name in VBA. However, I keep getting an error when doing so; error is saying Run-time error '1004'. My code is below

```
Sub CopyToRange()
    Dim TodaysDate as String

    TodaysDate = format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    activeworkbook.SaveAs "FileName" & TodaysDate & ".xlsm"

End Sub
```

Comment: Change the `/` to something else.

Comment: hello @BigBen - changing the / to a "." worked. Can you explain why that worked?